# How to call a function when installing application in Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I want to call a function when installing A **Cordova/Phonegap** application (for create database and insert records to that).

In fact I just wanna run this function only once.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for that :

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function()
{
    if (typeof window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime') === 'undefined')
    {
        // Execute some code for the installation
        // ...

        window.localStorage.setItem('firstTime', 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding an event listener to effectively run a single time, as in [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30764228/3614835), is correct, the syntax needs to be slightly different.

When running the following code:

```
console.log("First time?");
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime'));
console.log(typeof window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime'));
console.log(typeof window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime') === 'undefined');
```

The following is seen in the Javascript console:

```
First time?
null
object
false
```

Additionally, the Mozilla documentation for Storage.getItem() says it [returns 'null' when a non-existent key is requested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem#Returns):

> **Returns**
>
> A DOMString containing the value of the key. If the key does not exist, null is returned.

Thus, to make this work, I needed to use the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function()
{
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime') == null)
    {
        // Execute some code for the installation
        // ...

        window.localStorage.setItem('firstTime', 0);
    }
});
```